# how to get specific property name via rest call in strongloop loopback

Tags: rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am having students model in loopback which is accessible via rest using this url. `/api/students` rest call gives all the student data but I want to get only the registration numbers (regno) of students. Like in sql (SELECT `regno` FROM `students`). how I should filter the above rest call to get only the registration numbers of students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
?filter={"fields":"regno"}
```

If you want to get multiple columns

```
?filter={"fields":["regno","column2","column3",....]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the fields filter.

```
?filter[fields][regno]=true
```

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Fields+filter